# How to add an Admin to a Facebook Page via a webpage button (through API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Hello and thank you ahead of time for the help.

I would like to do the following but I would like for this process to be initiated via a webpage button (through API), if possible.

Click Settings at the top of your Page.
Click Page Roles in the left column.
Type a name or email in the box:  admin_email_address_here@somedomain.com
Click Editor to select a role from the dropdown menu. - Administrator
Click Save and enter your password to confirm.

Example: Client clicks a webpage button and grants Admin rights to a particular Facebook Page to the person who's email address is admin_email_address_here@somedomain.com

Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible via Graph API.

You can *read* the accounts assigned to the different page roles via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/roles/ - but if you look into the “Creating” section on that page, it says

> “You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.”